# Laravel Delete record in a row is not as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using resource controller to delete record in row by passing a collection into the view.

**View**:

```
<tbody>
                                @php $count=1; @endphp
                                @forelse ($products as $product)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $count }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->slug }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $product->updated_at }}</td>
                                        <td><span class="label label-success">Published</span></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <a href="/products/{{ $product->slug }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">View</a>
                                                <a href="/account/edit-product-{{ $product->slug }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</a>
                                                <a href="{{ route('products.destroy', $product->slug) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('delete-product').submit();">Delete</a>

                                                <form id="delete-product" method="POST" action="{{ route('products.destroy', $product->slug) }}" style="display: none;">
                                                    @csrf
                                                    @method('DELETE')
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @php $count++; @endphp
                                @empty
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="6">No products yet.</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforelse
                            </tbody>
```

**Controller**:

```
public function products()
    {
        $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        return view('vendor.products')->with('products', $products);
    }
public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect('/account/products')->with('success', 'Product deleted successfully.');
    }
```

When I click any of the "Delete" button, it deletes the last post (the first post in database, since it is sorted in descending).

Can someone tells me where it is wrong? I think initally the code work just fine, until I make some other modification and it is "magically" did not work as expected.

Edited:
route:

```
Route::prefix('/account')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/products', 'AccountController@products');
    Route::get('/corporate-info', 'AccountController@corporateInfo');
    Route::get('/add-product', 'ProductController@create');
    Route::get('/edit-product-{product}', 'ProductController@edit');
});

Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

Product model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the section of code where your route is defined e.g. web.php? It's probably a conflict in the routing.

Comment: I've added the route section.

Comment: You should be passing the data as an array, i.e. `route('products.destroy', ['product'=>$product->slug])`. Presumably you have added the `getRouteKeyName` function to your `Product` model?

Comment: Yes. I've added the `getRouteKeyName` method on Product model. But the result still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh here is your issue :

```
 <a href="{{ route('products.destroy', $product->slug) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('delete-product').submit();">Delete</a>

<form id="delete-product" method="POST" action="{{ route('products.destroy', $product->slug) }}" style="display: none;">
       @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
</form>
```

You are giving the same id 'delete-product' to each form while looping therefore whenever you are

> document.getElementById('delete-product').submit();

Its getting and submitting the form with the delete-product id which is the last one due to overriding issue to solve your issue :

```
 <a href="{{ route('products.destroy', $product->slug) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('delete-product-{{$product->slug}}').submit();">Delete</a>

<form id="delete-product-{{$product->slug}}" method="POST" action="{{ route('products.destroy', $product->slug) }}" style="display: none;">
   @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
</form>
```

Comment: btw you don't need the href attribute over here .

Comment: Oh I see.. Didn't notice about the form is affected by the loop. Seems a lot more to me. Btw thank you so much,,